# GET request going to front-end not back-end on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, get

I have a MERN app that submits axios requests to a NodeJS backend server, but the requests are for some reason going to the front-end instead of the back-end. When set up locally the app works fine, but on Heroku it gives this error:

```
GET https://heroku-app-name.herokuapp.com/app/order?query=soap&page=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The request is trying to `GET` from the front-end. Why is the proxy to the back-end no longer working?

Answer (score 0):

After extensively looking at the logs, I discovered the app *was* going to the back-end for its API call, however, the MongoDB collection was created improperly. Fixing this has restored the app's functionality.